# Problems with forward and backwards search in sublime (latextools)

Tags: ubuntu, forward-inverse-search, sublime-text

Even though I've done everything as I should in the sublime settings, I cant get forward or backward search to function. I am using sublime2 on ubuntu, where I have both python2.7 and python3 is installed. The program is built using ctrl+b, and the PDF is automatically opened using document viewer.

```
// LaTeXTools Preferences
//
// Keep in the User directory. Personalize as needed

{


// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// General settings
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Cite/ref autocompletion by default is triggered after e.g. \ref{. If you don't like this,
    // set to false. You can also use toggles: C-l,t,a,c and C-l,t,a,r.
    "cite_auto_trigger": true,
    "ref_auto_trigger": true, 


    // Keep focus on Sublime Text after building (true) or switch to PDF viewer (false)
    "keep_focus": true,
    // Sync PDF to current editor position after building (true) or not 
    "forward_sync": true,


// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Platform settings: adapt as needed for your machine
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

    "linux" : {
        // Path used when invoking tex & friends; MUST include $PATH
        "texpath" : "$PATH:/usr/texmaker",
        // Command to invoke Python 2. Useful if you have both Python 2 and Python 3 on your system,
        // and "python" by default is liked to Python 3. If blank, "python" is used
        // Note: ST3 uses Python 3 internally, but the evince scripts need Python 2
        "python2": "python2.7",
        // The name of the ST2 or ST3 executable. On Ubuntu, both subl and sublime-text are 
        // available for ST2; adjust as needed for other platforms, and for ST3
        "sublime": "subl",
        // How long to wait after evince has launched before sending a sync message
        // in seconds, floating point; choose 2.0 or 3.0 on a slower machine, 0.5 on a fast one
        // Note: only tweak this if sync after launching the PDF viewer does not seem to work,
        // or if the PDF viewer opens instantly and you don't want to wait.
        // Default: 1.5 (works on my MBP4,1...)
        "sync_wait": 1.5,
        "forward_sync": true
    },

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Build engine settings
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

    // OPTION: "builder"
    // Specifies a build engine
    // Possible values:
    //
    // "default" or ""  the default built-in build engine; currently
    //                  this is the same as "traditional"
    //
    // "simple"         invokes pdflatex 1x or 2x as needed, then
    //                  bibtex and pdflatex again if needed;
    //                  intended mainly as a simple example for
    //                  peoeple writing their own build engines.
    //
    // "traditional"    replicates the 'old' system based on
    //                  latexmk (TeXLive) / texify (MiKTeX)
    //
    // "script"         external script: just invokes the script
    //                  specified in "builder_settings"
    //
    // custom name      you can also use third-party build engines;
    //                  if so, set the "builder_path" option below
    //
    // NOTE: custom builders CANNOT have the same name as an existing
    // built-in build engine (including "default")

    "builder": "traditional",

    // OPTION: "builder_path"
    // If non-empty, specifies a path to a custom builder, relative to the
    // Sublime Text Packages directory.
    // For instance, "User/builders" (on Windows: "User\builders") is a good
    // choice if you roll your own. 
    // (Note: if you choose "User", you may get a Python import error in the
    // console, but things will still work). 
    // Leave empty ("") for a built-in builder.

    "builder_path": "",

    // OPTION: "builder_settings"
    // Specify builder-dependent settings and preferences
    // Possible values: see README or documentation provided with
    // third-party build engine.
    // Builder setting can be general or OS-dependent

    "builder_settings" : {

        // General settings:
        // See README or third-party documentation

        // (built-ins): true shows the log of each command in the output panel
        "display_log" : false,  

        // Platform-specific settings:
        "osx" : {
            // See README or third-party documentation
        },

        "windows" : {
            // See README or third-party documentation
        },

        "linux" : {
            // See README or third-party documentation
        }
    },

}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Did you try to ask StackOverflow? Probably there are more sublime experts.

Comment: Have you setup your pdf-viewer to be used with sublime text?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RudFaden . No I have not, the PDF is opened in document viewer. How is this done?

Comment: It depends on the pdf viewer you use. I think it should be in the latextools guide.

Comment: Looked it up. It should work out of the box with evince. Are you sure you are using the right keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Thank you. I'm using ctrl+B to build, I'm unsure if there are any other way to do it.

Comment: You should use shortcuts to activate search. See the manual

Comment: I am trying the shortcud, but it doesn't give any response. Thank you for your answer.